# How to add a tree inside a custom section in umbraco 6.1.x

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5, umbraco6

I tried to add tree nodes to the tree.config. but it seems not to work, is there anything which I am missing?

Comment: @Robert Harvey why have you put my question on  hold, this question is very clear and it is having proper context only for the Umbraco developers. If you are not able to understand the question then it seems you don't work on umbraco.

Comment: Please check here:  [How to add a tree inside a custom section in umbraco](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+add+a+tree+inside+custom+section+in+umbraco), and tell us what you've tried and why it didn't work.